# Python application to run on Mac and Windows - can I develop in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, ubuntu

I know a bit of programming and I know python. Lately I have been making a program for myself that reads off an excel file I get from my bank and puts everything into different categories. My sister and her husband uses the same bank and they have said that they also want to use the program, but they are not comfortable with using terminals and are easily scared by it. I have never used GUIs before, and my question is therefore:

Is there a good GUI that let me write everything in Ubuntu and test it out there, that also work on Windows/MAC without having to install a bunch of libraries etc on the users computers?

Comment: Try [PyQt](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/), [PySide](http://www.pyside.org/) or [Tkinter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter).

Comment: Look also at [wxPython](https://wxpython.org/). You can use then [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) to package your project as Windows `.exe` executable or OS X `.app` bundle.